# Compiling Multiple Godot Targets in One Scons Build

Tags: scons, godot

I have custom [godotengine/godot](https://github.com/godotengine/godot) project which necessitates building 3 separate build targets:

```
scons platform=x11 tools=no target=release bits=64
scons platform=x11 tools=no target=release_debug bits=64
scons platform=x11 target=debug
```

This takes a *really* long time to build (each time the compiler seems to start from scratch).

**Question:** Is there a way to compile all 3 of these build targets at once?

Comment: This is really just a godot question. There's nothing in SCons which prevents building all possible variants at the same time.

Comment: "This takes a really long time to build (each time the compiler seems to start from scratch)." - Compiler has no other way than compiling each source file once for each configuration, because these configuration implies **different compilation options**. So it is not clear what do you want to achieve by compiling these 3 build targets "at once" - this won't give you a speed up in the compilation.